# Mysql reset auto_increment not for new ids but for all (also old ids)

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

Hi all is there any SQL function to reset all auto_increment ids?

I mean , i have this situation (id =1 , id2 = 2, id3 =3)

once i delete id i would like to be returned this situation (id2 = 1, id3 = 2) and so on.

Need i a script to do that?

Comment: Did you understand that it will broke foreign keys in other tables, links to your site etc?

Comment: i know that but it is just a slideshow gallery table ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the whole table:

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

But you cannot really go back to fill in values in individual rows that have been deleted.  The `auto_increment` values are intended to be unique, but aren't guaranteed to remain sequential if deletions happen or new rows are inserted with an explicit value set for the `auto_increment` column.

If you needed to modify them to be sequential again, it would have to be done in code, probably looping over all rows and performing `UPDATE` statements individually.

Comment: uhm .. it doesn't works cause if i have my table starting from 6 it doesn't change to 1 first record and then other records sequentially :(

Comment: @memento See the rest of my answer. `auto_increment` cannot effectively be used to guarantee sequential numbering.  That isn't its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Id is Id which means it must **never change**! At least in good database design. Id is something you are born with and you die with.

Comment: I wouldn't say never.  You can enforce foreign key relationships with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in InnoDB tables.

Comment: i do not have foreign keys is a unique record i do not need any foreign keys or changes in future ;)

Comment: @Michael: yes, you could do that, but I think you shouldn't for many other reasons. E.g. the ids can be "out" of the current database (in other database, in URLS, in other versions of the database - e.g. backups or copies you gave to anyone else), so with changing ids you are doing a big mess and can run into trouble when you are confronted with the "previous version of ids"....

Comment: @both please guys :) this is a stupid table .. i know about database optimization but i really need this functionality :P  ... no sql functions to do that? need i script? :P thanks ;)

Comment: @memento: what you probably need is a new column. Make a new column and don't use id for that! Id should be just for identification (and not anything else!), that's why it's called id!

Comment: @memento: or tell us what you want to do, there might be easier solution than trying to do this.

Comment: np guys i just need a script as i can see thanks anyway (really np ;) )